# Laplace eigenvalue and floer theory

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, laplacian, floer-homology, flows

I'm trying to study the spectrum operator via Floer Theory. The idea is to consider the Rayleigh quotient as an operator on the Hilbert space $W^{1,2}$ and to study it's negative gradient flow.

Any idea of how to recover the well-known results about its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions? Or do you have any concrete example of such a method?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? Which "well-known results" do you mean exactly?

Comment: I suggest that you first try this for a real symmetric $N\times N$ matrix. In any case. if the eigenvalues are simple,  what you will discover is   a perfect complex computing the homology of $\mathbb{RP}^N$.    In any case,  this is a classical example, good as an exercise.

Comment: I wish I could find again that it possesses an infinite countable number of eigenvalues , that the first on is simple,etc.... I need to study the negative gradient flow associated to thé Rayleigh quotient. I read many things about Floer theory but I am very new with it, and I must admit I haven't manager yet to make everything clear. I wanted to start with an easy example, yet it still is challenging for me. THANK you Liviu Nicolaescu, I'm going to try this.